# Save ratingBar rating in sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

Hello everyone :) I've been working on a rating bar, it works perfectly, the only issue is it does not save the rating after a user leaves the page or the application. One of SO's users named Lal helped me out and I have it all set up but seem to be doing something wrong still. The way it works is I have a listview in main-activity, when you click on a listview row it calls a new class which loads the corresponding page. On the corresponding page is a ratingBar. I do not call the ratingbar in mainactivity, I call it in the class main_activity calls in reference to the row clicked.

**Here is the code where the rating bar is in ListItemActivity1.java**

```
RatingBar ratingBar;
TextView ratingText;
SharedPreferences wmbPreference1;    
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;         
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.list_item_activity_1);      
ratingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);
((RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1))
.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);  
wmbPreference1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
float rating = wmbPreference1.getFloat("numStars", 0f);
ratingBar.setRating(rating);
}   
@Override
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
boolean fromTouch) {        
final int numStars = ratingBar.getNumStars();
editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
editor.putFloat("numStars", rating);
editor.commit();      
int ratings = wmbPreference1.getInt("numStars", 0);
ratingText.setText(rating + "/" + String.valueOf(ratings));
}
}
```

The problem occurs on the last line of the code. I get an error that says Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int. Am i supposed to have a string setup for this? Another issue is, with the new code, I get an error in the emulator when i try to reload in the console saying splash screen cannot load, activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front. It all seems to be stemming from the shared preferences and last line of code above.

Any help would be appreciated, I've been stuck on this rating bar for a while ^^ and really would like to move on to more pressing parts of the application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the int value to string, use `String.valueOf(ratings)`.

Anyway, your code has a couple of other issues. In `onRatingChanged()` I assume you want to save the current rating into the SharedPreferences. That variable would be `rating` (since `getNumStars()` returns the total number of stars, not the current value).

To save this value, you should do it with the editor, before committing, i.e.

```
editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
editor.putFloat("numStars", rating);
editor.commit();
```

And to restore it in `onCreate()`, do:

```
float rating = wmbPreference1.getFloat("numStars", 0f);
ratingBar.setRating(rating);
```

Comment: Hey Matiash, I updated the code above with what you suggested but am unsure how to implement the String.valueOf(ratings) line? Any help would be appreciated, this is the first time I've used shared preferences with a ratingBar.

Comment: @user3606168 That applied only to the last line, when you show the "4/5" text. Use `ratingText.setText(rating + "/" + String.valueOf(ratings));`

Comment: Thanks Matiash, I updated the code above. There are no more errors but when I try to open the page the app crashes :( Any other ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @acro I would recommend asking another question, posting the offending code and the full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks Matiash. Problem solved, everything is running perfect, and I actually did ask another question :) Thanks again..